# How to suppress logging of some requests in logback-access?

Tags: slf4j, logback

I'm using logback-access with Jetty. It's working fine, except that http requests for images (`*.jpg`, `*.gif`) are getting logged. Most app servers suppress these log records because they bloat the logs.

When I was using the old Jetty `NCSARequestLog` object, there was a `setIgnorePaths()` method that worked, but the logback `RequestLogImpl` doesn't have a similar method.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it in `logback-access.xml`, perhaps using some kind of filter. Does anyone have the appropriate syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple `EvaluatorFilter` configuration, copy inside your appender:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator>
            <expression>
            return formattedMessage.contains(".jpg") ||
                formattedMessage.contains(".gif"); 
            </expression>
        </evaluator>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    ...
```

Maybe you should customize the expression, since `.gif` and `.jpg` could occur in other log messages too.

`EvaluatorFilter` needs the following dependency. Put it to your `pom.xml` or add to your classpath if you don't use Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.16</version>
</dependency>
```

[Further EvaluatorFilter documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#evalutatorFilter)

Comment: Note: here you checking a formatted message instead of just URL, this is not optimal for performance

Answer (score 12):

logback-access has `ch.qos.logback.access.net.URLEvaluator` that can be used instead of inline scripts with Janino :

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.access.net.URLEvaluator">
            <URL>.jpg</URL>
            <URL>.gif</URL>
            <URL>https://example.com/static/</URL>
            <URL>/ops/</URL>
            <URL>/management/</URL>
            <URL>/monitoring</URL>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
    </filter>
   ...
```

Inside the `URLEvaluator` makes `contains()` so the matching can happens on any part of url.

IMHO it's better to avoid to use the Janino library

Comment: "IMHO it's better to avoid to use the Janino library" - why?

Comment: Because this is compiler and non standard compiler. It can have all issues that compilers may have, it can generate inefficient bytecode, it can have problems with JDK version. But also this is additional footprint in classpath.
Also this is bad style when you gave a developer ability to write too pretentious logic so other devs can't understand and support.
URLEvaluator is more clear than some java code snippet.

Comment: I agree, URLEvaluator is cleaner and more efficient.